VisualStudio 2022 No Debug Output from AutoCAD Assembly
VisualStudio fails to display any output written via Trace.WriteLine() or Debug.WriteLine(). I want to be able to write to, and view, debugging information for my assembly.
I have created a .dll that I load into AutoCAD using the 'NETLOAD' command. Within Visual Studio I then attach my debug output window to the process by going to 'Debug-->Attach to Process'. I see output from the acad.exe process, but none of my messages are displayed.
The output window has Program Output checked, and is set to show output from Debug. I believe all my other settings are correct but I must be missing something. Any ideas?
